# Is there a better way to deal with unique field in yii2 curd form?

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

In my yii2 form I have a field name `number`, which is unique in DB.

This `number` will be used for sorting in frontend.

Whats the best way to deal with this field in backend?

Comment: what DB u use ?

Comment: MySQL. I want to know how do i handle this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking how to create a **primary key**?   primary key must be unique here I declare `number_field` as primary key which is unique.

Here is an example of a table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
 `number_field` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `another_field` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `extra_field` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`number_field`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

also you can use **UNIQUE KEY** prop instead of **PRIMARY KEY**

you can change existing table like this

```
alter table 
your_table_name 
add unique (number_field)
```